# Why does vert count Increase when joining different objects into one?

Tags: modeling, vertices, .fbx

I have multiple objects, and I decide to combine them so that I can animate it in one Armature, but when I export it to FBX it drastically increased in vert count, I go back in the other save before I joined them and exported it, and its drastically smaller.

Objects when separated: 13,918 verts.

Objects when joined: 42,505 verts.

Why is this happening? and can you fix it? if yes, how?

Comment: May be there is a modifier somewhere.

Comment: yeah probably that, check for a subdivision surface modifier on the objects, and apply it before joining to fix the problem.

Comment: That's not it. I already did that before joining them.